# What is the maximum limit to fetch the attributes of a particular url in a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have around 5 to 6k URL's in excel sheet, and I need to build a **scraper** in Python with Beautiful soup package by fetching each URL in excel and scrape the required attributes in that particular URL, and I need to loop in for all 5k URL's.

Is it possible to do this at one shot?

Can the websites block us because of large volumes? Any other optimal method to do the same?

Kindly suggest on this!

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways you may consider:

1. Send Request periodically with certain interval like 10 times for every 5 seconds.
2. Use different IP proxy so It is hard for server to determine if the request comes from the same client.